# How to run my tests using the built DLL in an Azure DevOps Release pipeline?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps *build* pipeline that has been working for a long time.

Here is how I set it up:

[image: Build pipeline]

The pipeline contains the Restore, Build, Test & NuGet Packaging & Publish steps.

As it can be seen in the screenshot, the integration tests have been deactivated because they take some time to complete. So, I would like to move the execution of the integration tests to a *release* pipeline along with the NuGet Publish steps.

I do not see how I can run these integration tests in such pipeline. I thought calling `dotnet test` would work however it does not work: the command requires a `.csproj` file, not the built DLL. And, at this stage, the Release pipeline has to work in the artifact provided by the Build pipeline.

[image: Release pipeline]

As suggested in the comments, I see that `dotnet vstest` could be used but the option is not available on devops:

[image: dotnet options]

**Question**

How can I run my integration tests in an Azure DevOps Release pipeline?

Comment: I think you need to use `dotnet vstest` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest?tabs=netcore21 it accepts a list of DLLs to run tests from. If using something like xunit, I believe you need to have the associated vstest runner referenced by the test project.

Comment: @Kzrystof One thing i forgot to mention, you can add a **Publish build artifacts
** to publish the build dll files to release pipeline where you can run your test with **Visual Studio Test** task. I updated my answer. hope it can be helpful.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I will try this and mark the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

In order to test the test.dll files in release pipeline, You can add a **publish build artifacts task** right after your **dotnet build task**. Then you can test your test dlls in your release pipeline with **Visual Studio Test** task.
[image]

To run a custom dotnet command, You can specify the command to run in option **Custom command**

[image]

**Suggested:**

However there is another test task (**Visual Studio Test**) can run .dll.

[image]

Comment: Could you remove the broken images and put some explanations in their place please? In any case, this did help me to get it working. **Publish artifacts** in the build pipeline, **Download artifacts** in the release pipeline. Beware that **Publish artifacts** does not allow wildcards in its path. I struggled for a while before simply checking the precise path in the build output and pasting that in.